# Change a variable within a {{variable}} (don't know what that is called)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to change the variable "prefs" to either "easy, medium, or hard" based on user click.

Example:
THIS

```
{{choice.prefs.title}}
```

NEEDS TO CHANGE TO 
`{{choice.easy.price}}` or `{{choice.medium.price}}` or `{{choice.hard.price}}`

based on which button is clicked by the user

```
<button class="button button-stable" ng-click="prefs="easy"")>Change to Easy</button>
</div>

<button class="button button-stable" ng-click="diff='normal'">Change to Medium</button>
</div>

<button class="button button-stable" ng-click="diff='hard'">Change to Hard</button>
</div>
```

Manually typing 
`{{choice.easy.price}}` works but `{{choice.prefs.price}}` and `ng-click="pref='easy'"` does not work

Thanks for the help in advance

EDIT:
The array I am trying to access in my controller looks like this

```
allbooks={
book1:{
easy{title:"whatever"},
medium{title:"hello"},
hard{title:"another"}
},
book2:{
easy{title:"whatever"},
medium{title:"hello"},
hard{title:"another"}
},
book3:{
easy{title:"whatever"},
medium{title:"hello"},
hard{title:"another"}
},
}
```

Choice is assigned by a function that simply sets choice to `allbooks.book1` or `allbooks.book2` based on user clicks

So I need to combine `choice` and `prefs`

Thanks:)

Comment: Why change the variable? change the value

Comment: Could you elaborate (with some code ;) ).... I thought that was what I was doing with "prefs='easy'", just changing the value in the variable not the variable

Answer (score 2):

You may do something like this:

```
<button class="button button-stable" ng-click="prefs='easy'")>Change to Easy</button>
</div>

<button class="button button-stable" ng-click="prefs='normal'">Change to Medium</button>
</div>

<button class="button button-stable" ng-click="prefs='hard'">Change to Hard</button>
</div>
```

and use: `$scope[prefs].title` instead of `$scope.prefs.title`
 (Use `[]` notation instead of the `.` notation when referencing variable object properties)

Comment: Will `prefs='easy'` change the `prefs` property from the `object` ?

Comment: `prefs='easy'` will set the value of the variable `prefs`, which is referenced here: `$scope[prefs].title`

Comment: But I still need to have "choice" as that is necessary to access a certain part of the array... so would it be "choice[prefs].title".....the array in the controller looks like this essentially: Please see edit @AvijitGupta

Comment: @MehdiN Please clarify. Your edit did not suggest something useful, and it was rejected by reviewers.

Comment: Sorry, can you see my edit of my questions... (I added the array in my controller)...basically I need to keep the `choice` part and add the `prefs` part but in your solution you eliminated `choice` and put `$scope`

Comment: @MehdiN So you can do something like `$scope[choice][prefs].title`